# json post request by sending parameters dynamically in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am trying to call JSON post request using AFNetworking using custom delegate methods.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager =  [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:loginURL parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON Successsss: %@", responseObject);
    NSLog(@"operation Successsss: %@", operation);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
    NSLog(@"Error laaa: %@", error);
}];}
```

And am getting errro like this...

```
No visible interface "AFHttpRequestOperationManager" decleared the selector ::param
@ at line  [manager POST:loginURL parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
```

so any one can help in this issue...Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Because after AFNetworking 3.x, there is no AFHTTPRequestOperationManager . You should use AFHTTPSessionManager instead.

**Example**

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1/123.php"]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST: loginURL
   parameters:parameters
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
          NSLog(@"responseObject : %@", responseObject);
      } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"error : %@", error);
      }];
```

Comment: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)"

Comment: i want to call json request using custom delegate methods.Handle that json response in viewcontroller class ....Can you please help me in this issuance

Comment: No,url is working correctly.but am getting error like this...NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146416/discussion-between-shaik-tamim-and-kkrocks).